Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) met trying to plot the average marginal effect of an interaction term
I encountered an issue when trying to plot the average marginal effect of an interaction term in my logistic regression model, and I hoped you could provide some guidance.
After fitting my logistic regression model using svyglm in R using the following command,


fit7a <- svyglm(formula = visa ~ age + male + married + chimin +
parret + famtiegravsponsor+conf + offwhite + offm + married *age,
design = survey_design, family = binomial(), rescale = TRUE)


I attempted to plot the average marginal effect for the interaction term between age and married with the following commands in ggeffects: I tried out three commands, here age is a continuous variable, and married is a binary variable :

result <- predict_response(fit7a, c("age[all]", "married")) plot_model(fit7a, type = "pred", terms = c("age[all]", "married"))
ggpredict(fit7a, terms = c("age[all]", "married"))

Unfortunately, each of these attempts returned the same error:


Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :   error in evaluating the
argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'drop':
non-conformable arguments


I would be very grateful if anyone could help me understand what might be causing this error and suggest a solution. Please let me know if I can provide any additional details.
